# Numpy arrays - Multidimensional logic comparison

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying find the entries in a two-dimensional array that are above a certain threshold. The thresholds for the individual columns is given by a one-dimensional array. To exemplify,

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [2, 0, 4]]
```

is the two-dimensional array and I want to see if where in the columns values are bigger than

```
[2, 1, 3]
```

so the output of running the operation should be

```
[[False, True, False]
 [True, True, True],
 [False, False, True]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Something is wrong in your example. For example, why a True value corresponds to 0? 0 is clearly smaller than all your thresholds.

Comment: Changed clearly need a break

Comment: Still does not compute :) 6 is greater than any element, but has a False value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, assuming there's an error in the example, I would simply do:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[2, 0, 4]])
T = np.array([2, 1, 3])

X = A > T
```

Which gives

```
array([[False,  True, False],
   [ True,  True,  True],
   [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: +1. This is why it happens: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be inconsistencies in your example (e.g. 2 > 1 is True, yet 2 > 4 is True) - can you clarify this?

Assuming you you want to know, for each row, which columns of the values in the first list are greater than the `[2,1,3]` list you gave, I suggest the following:

```
import numpy as np

tmp = [[1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [2, 0, 4]]

output = [ np.less([2, 1, 3], tmp[i]) for i in range(len(tmp))]
```

Similarly, try `greater` or `greater_equal` or `less_equal` for the result you're after:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html